# Possible values for apt-get "Automatic-Reboot-Time"

Tags: apt, reboot, unattended-upgrades

`/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades` says the default automatic reboot time is now, unless you set it to a time.  The time that is puts in the config file and comments out is `02:00` but I don't want to set it to a particular time of day. I've got weekly maintenance windows for my ubuntu servers and I want to set it to then.  Is this just a parameter for an at job?  In other words, can I reboot my servers at "Wednesday at Tea Time"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `unattended-upgrade` program is a python script, the relevant portion of which appears to be:

```
# reboot at the specified time
when = apt_pkg.config.find(
    "Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot-Time", "now")
if shutdown_lock > 0:
    os.close(shutdown_lock)
logging.warning("Found %s, rebooting" % REBOOT_REQUIRED_FILE)
subprocess.call(["/sbin/shutdown", "-r", when])
```

Hence the time formats supported are those supported by `/sbin/shutdown`, namely (from `man shutdown`):

```
The time string may either be in the format "hh:mm" for hour/minutes
specifying the time to execute the shutdown at, specified in 24h clock
format. Alternatively it may be in the syntax "+m" referring to the
specified number of minutes m from now.  "now" is an alias for "+0",
i.e. for triggering an immediate shutdown. If no time argument is
specified, "+1" is implied.
```

Answer (score 3):

The current version in the Ubuntu-repositories doesn't support this yet.

However, if you clone the [current version](https://github.com/mvo5/unattended-upgrades) from GitHub, you can set Update-Days like: `{"Tue"};` in your config file, so it will only reboot on Tuesdays at your specified time.

Comment: Is this now part of Ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: I think this option controls how often updates are applied, rather than how often a reboot occurs. I'm looking to install updates daily, but only reboot weekly.